# Password Validation based on image Changes in swift

Tags: swift, swift3

Hi Good morning every one please any one to solve this issues

I had 4 images one password filed 
here when user enter capital and small letter and I need to tick one image 
again user enter enter number in textfield I need to tick another image
again user enter special character I need to tick another image

if user remove character based on that I need to deselect the image any one help to solve this issues 
here is my code

```
  @IBAction func textFieldEditingChanged(_ sender: Any) {
             viewPasswordStrength.isHidden = false
            if isValidated(passwordTextField.text!){

               print("succ")
            }
        }   
        func isValidated(_ password: String) -> Bool {
            var lowerCaseLetter: Bool = false
            var upperCaseLetter: Bool = false
            var digit: Bool = false
            var specialCharacter: Bool = false

                for char in password.unicodeScalars {
                    if !lowerCaseLetter {
                        lowerCaseLetter = CharacterSet.lowercaseLetters.contains(char)

                    }
                    if !upperCaseLetter {
                        upperCaseLetter = CharacterSet.uppercaseLetters.contains(char)
                    }
                    if !digit {
                        digit = CharacterSet.decimalDigits.contains(char)

                   }

                    if !specialCharacter {
                        specialCharacter = CharacterSet.punctuationCharacters.contains(char)

                    }


                }
            if  ( lowerCaseLetter && upperCaseLetter) {
                //do what u want
                self.UpperCaseImageConditions_img.image = UIImage(named: "GreenTick")
                return true
            }

             if  (specialCharacter) {
                //do what u want
                self.SpecialCharacter_img.image = UIImage(named: "GreenTick")
                return true
            }
                if  ( digit) {
                    //do what u want
                    self.onenumberImageCondiotion_img.image = UIImage(named: "GreenTick")
                    return true
                }
                else {
                    self.UpperCaseImageConditions_img.image = UIImage(named: "redtick")
                    return false
                }
       }
```

here I cannot change the image based on the user enter the text in password filed
THANKS IN ADVANCE

Comment: check the last character of your textfield, like this `let lastCharacter = passwordTextField.text!.suffix(1)`

Comment: I need to check the given string from text filed with every validation based on the validation need to change I ages